# Magento top menu dropdown is not working in homepage

Tags: magento, drop-down-menu, navigation

**Top menu dropdown is not working only in homepage**. It's working fine in innerpages. I'm having a banner slider extension and custom jquery slider in my homepage i thought the issue is with jquery conflict.

Did anyone overcome these kind of problem before? Please share your comments to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: That is really a vague question. You have some extensions, jquery and so on. If you want to make sure that is not jQuery conflict then check here for jQuery.noconflict. Test it and see if it's still happens.

Comment: I agree with Ovidiu, that seems to be that you enabled jQuery without enabling the noconflict mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.noConflict()` in your jQuery file, to avoid conflict with prototype library
See this [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)